# Why isn't .data attribute obsolete/deprecated in favor of .detach() in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I know that `.detach()` is safer in that it catches in-place modifications that will cause autograd to give wrong results when backpropagating through the graph.

Does, it mean that in the newer code we longer need to use `.data`, and we can use `.detach()` everywhere, whenever we need it?

Comment: Check out this issue thread on GitHub: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/6990

Comment: I get the difference between `.data` and `.detach()`, but this does not answer my question, that is it possible to use `.detach()` instead of every use case of `.data`?